# Can a bounded open set in $R^n$ be always approximated from outside with a finite union of dyadic cubes?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Suppose we have a bounded open set $S$ in $R^n$. Consider the collection of closed dyadic cubes $C_k$'s (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_cubes). I was wondering if there always exists a finite positive integer $K$ such that 
(1) $S \subset \cup_{k=1}^K C_k$ and (2) $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^K C_k) < \mu(S)+\epsilon$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure in $R^n$.

Thanks very much!

Comment: A set admits such an approximation iff its boundary has Lebesgue measure $0$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure), so the complement of a fat Cantor set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) in a ball would be a counterexample.